# Minimum margin for a centered background-image when window resizes

Tags: css, positioning, background-image, margins

I have a background image that's centered vertically and horizontally using CSS.  It looks great and is working as long as the window is large enough to display the background image.

The problem I have occurs when the window is resized to be smaller than the bg image.  When this happens, the bg image continues to be centered, but I instead need to maintain a minimum margin around the top and left of the bg image.  The BG image is 900px x 700px, and the code I've used is:

```
#main_wrapper {
    background-image: url(../images/background.jpg);
    position:relative;
    width:900px;
    height:700px;
    left:50%;
    top:50%;
    margin-left:-450px;
    margin-top:-350px;
}
```

Any solution would need to continue to center the bg image horizontally and vertically when the window is large enough to allow it, but would have a minimum margin at the top when the window is shorter than the bg image, and a minimum margin at the left when the window is narrower than the bg image.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If this is in your `<body>`, I'd add two extra divs right at the beginning of the body, positioned absolute, and having a background-color of white, to make sure that in that area, the background image isn't seen.

Then wrap the rest of what you had in the body in a `<div>` and have it be `position: relative`.

I think this should result in what you want.